# Conditionally drop Pandas Dataframe row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I wish to drop rows where the rows just before and just after has the same value for the column `num2`.
My dataframe looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [12, 10],
    [11, 10],
    [13, 10],
    [42, 11],
    [4, 11],
    [5, 2]
], columns=["num1", "num2"]
)
```

And this is my target:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [12, 10],
    [13, 10],
    [42, 11],
    [4, 11],
    [5, 2]
], columns=["num1", "num2"]
)
```

What I have tried:

```
df["num1_diff"] = df["num2"].diff().fillna(0).astype(int)
filt = df["num1_diff"].apply(lambda x: x == 0)
print(df[filt])
```

Giving:

```
   num1  num2  num1_diff
0    12    10          0
1    11    10          0
2    13    10          0
4     4    11          0
```

And I was thinking to use the new `num1_diff` column to do the filtering.
Is this a good approach, or is there perhaps a better one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Series.shift` twice, and check where `num2` equals:

```
df[df['num2'].shift().ne(df['num2'].shift(-1))]

   num1  num2
0    12    10
2    13    10
3    42    11
4     4    11
5     5     2
```

Comment: Be careful, this solution drops the row even if the current row does not have same value as the two rows next and before. Is it the behaviour expected ?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC,

```
df.loc[df['num2'].diff() != df['num2'].diff(-1)]
```

Output

```
   num1  num2
0    12    10
2    13    10
3    42    11
4     4    11
5     5     2
```

if you need all three to match:

```
df.loc[df['num2'].diff().bfill().rolling(3, center=True).sum().eq(0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you only want to drop rows where the rows just before and just after **AND the current row** have the same value for the column num2, use :

```
df[~(df['num2'].eq(df['num2'].shift()) & df['num2'].eq(df['num2'].shift(-1)))]
```

Here is an example :

```
   num1  num2
0    12    10
1    11    10
2    13    10
3     1    26
4     2     7  # <---- Do you want to drop this value ? if yes, consider Erfan 's solution
5     3    26       # if you want to keep it, I proposed another solution b)
```

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [12, 10],
    [11, 10],
    [13, 10],
    [1, 26],
    [2, 7],
    [3, 26]
], columns=["num1", "num2"]
)
a = df[df['num2'].shift().ne(df['num2'].shift(-1))] # Erfan 's solution
b = df[~(df['num2'].eq(df['num2'].shift()) & df['num2'].eq(df['num2'].shift(-1)))]

print(a)
print(b)
```

Output :

```
# a
   num1  num2
0    12    10
2    13    10
3     1    26
4     2     7
5     3    26

# b
   num1  num2
0    12    10
2    13    10
3     1    26
5     3    26
```